# Value not binding to model when using ng-if and ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 html views binded to 3 controllers in my angular js application.

```
A.html -> ACntrl
B.html -> BCntrl
C.html -> CCntrl
```

The functionality of these 3 views work as expected.

Now I have created a new view D.html where I am reusing the existing views instead of duplicating the code
    D.html -> DCntrl

```
<div ng-init="init()">
<div>
<div ng-if="conditionA" ng-controller="ACntrl" ng-include="'A.html'">  
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div ng-if="conditionB" ng-controller="BCntrl" ng-include="'B.html'">   
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div ng-if="conditionC"  ng-controller="CCntrl" ng-include="'C.html'">
</div>
</div>
```

The views are rendered properly based on the conditions..
However when I enter some value in a text field , the value does not bind to the model.

```
<input id="userInput" ng-model="userData" />
```

Is anything wrong with the implementation?

Comment: Are you using DCtrl as a wrapper for the other ctrls?

Comment: where is the text field ? Try creating a plunkr to replicate the issue.

Comment: No, DCntrl is not a wrapper for the other ctrls.Its a seperate controller..which sets the values for conditionA,conditionB and conditionC. The text field is in one of the included html which is rendered on the view

Comment: @girish included in **which** html? You have altogether 4 htmls here. Where is the text field rendered, A,B,C, or D html?

Comment: Its included in C.html.. but i think the issue should occur for other htmls as well..

Comment: The issue seemed to be related to scope.

<input id="userInput" ng-model="$parent.userData" />

works.
The fix was to specify ng-controller in the included html, instead of the outside div element. In my application the ng-controller was specified in the route configuration